# Dragon Project: Unwrapping issues

Tags: uv, baking, topology

Here is what I have accomplished so far:

1. I have sculpted out what I wanted my dragon to look like
2. I re-topologized the dragon into a much less dense design.
3. I tried my best to unwrap this design to no avail.
4. I crafted a normal map (Which works very poorly)

I currently still use Blender 2.79 because I really like it, the main thing that I am trying to accomplish is to just one time get one model done all the way through.

I have sculpted a lot of my works, but every time I retopologize and then try to unwrap I always get a disgusting mess as a result. I have seen tons of tutorials on the entire process and I have never seen anything like my result.

So, sometimes when you have no other options you just have to take a step back and throw yourself on to someone's feet and beg for help. I really love this kind of art and have been stuck on this for months.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong or even how to correct this issue. I can even send you my blend file for further observation if it will help.

This is my original completed sculpt
[image: This is my original completed sculpt]

This is my re-topologized mesh
[image: This is my re-topologized mesh]

This is a representation of the unwrap that I have
[image: This is a representation of the unwrap that I have]

These are the steps I took to apply the normal map
[image: These are the steps I took to apply the normal map]

The seams are pretty bad and that you can still see that my dragon is polygonal as ever
[image: This is a tad dark, but it doesn't take a lot of light to see that the seams are pretty bad and that you can still see that my dragon is polygonal as ever]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/12t99_Vl1bkYhNsxou2SUD3qYkjIGotnd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello and welcome :). You can share the .blend file through our [Blend-Exchange site](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/). Just remove all unnecessary parts and images to keep it as small as possible :).

Comment: Can we have a look at the texture, you're using? Also you might want to switch to smooth shaded when trying out normal maps.

Comment: Jachym, I will go ahead and share it now! I didn't know that we could do that!

Comment: Fredrick! I will put the whole blend file up on the blend exchange for you two! Thank you both for considering helping.

Comment: I am currently attempting to get this thing uploaded and have been for the last hour. It keeps getting stuck about a third way through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get useful answers try to ask more focused questions.
It's not really clear where exactly you're stuck.

Feel free to post as many **specific** questions as you need, that's what this site is for :).

---

To adress small technical issues:

- Repair non-manifold vertices *(Select > All By Trait > Non Manifold)*
- Align the centerline more precisely (to mirror properly)
- Correct Face orientation, as some are pointing the wrong way
- To get rid of the rough polygonal look, you can use 2 levels of *Subdivision Modifier.*

To align the centerline enable *Absolute Grid Snap*.
You can use *Scale tool* to align more vertices at once.

[image]

Other tips

- Use more circular edge loops on your model for easier unwrapping
- Add more seams when possible, to limit the stretching
- Learn more about making Normal Maps (you can learn a lot on this site)
- Try the new Blender Remesher (since Blender 2.82)

For art critique, you can try [BlenderArtists.com](https://blenderartists.org/).

---

Repaired mesh with some simple materials and a new UV map.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for at least taking a look at correcting the issues I had with my mesh! I really appreciate you even considering helping me.

Comment: No problem, I'm trying to unwrap it and it's really fun :). I'm learning a lot here, because I don't sculpt myself.

Comment: Jachym, Thank you so much! Just out of curiosity...how did you align the center-line more precisely? I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I used grid snapping. I'll add a gif to the answer :).

Comment: Jachym, you saved me a big headache. I am going to take what you have done and apply it to my own model and then take it a few steps further. Thank you so much for taking some time to help a struggling novice!

Comment: Happy to help :). Please mark this answer as accepted **✓** for now. You can post new questions if you get stuck somewhere. Good luck.